# body { background: url (3.jpg) not working

Tags: html, css

I'm building a simple landing page, the image file is found in the same folder with the html and css files. After applying the

the image failed to display. The image file shows up in the debuging tool

```
body { background-image: url ("../Landing page/3.jpg") ect...}
body { background-image: url ("..Landing page/3.jpg") ect...}
body { background: url ("../Landing page/3.jpg") ect...}
body { background: url ("../Landing page/3.jpg") ect...}
body { background-image: url ("..3.jpg") ect...}
body { background-image: url ("../3.jpg") ect...}
body { background: url ("3.jpg") ect...}
body { background: url ("../3.jpg") ect...}
```

I've changed the names of the files, documents as well. At this point I have no idea what else I could have missed

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: URL (" 3.jpg ");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: Open the chrome debugger network tab and check if there are any failed network requests

Comment: no failed request

Comment: Can you provide more of your html and css

Comment: try renaming your folder name most browser stop with first space so.... rename Landing page to Landingpage and let see what happen.

Comment: it was the folder naming as well once i tried it out as well

Comment: why do you have a space in " 3.jpg" in the second example. and what's 'etc', just paste all the code here, you might eventually have a problem there. also it's not clear why you have 8 different rules in the first snippet, I assume you tries all of those seperately

Comment: you need background-image:url("3.jpg") and a file with a name '"3.jpg" in the same folder, then it will work. No spaces anywhere (or anything else)

Comment: You need to understand relative and absolute URLs.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check for errors and failed requests.

2) Might be the extension of the image is not jpg but jpeg. Check for the extension.

3) Check the correct path of the images.

4) Both are correct `background-image: url('imgPath');` or `background: url('imgPath');`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be:

`background-image: url('/your/path');`

Comment: @velimir Tchatchevsky I am unsure if it works both ways, but your URL is in caps, every example you posted is lowercase

Comment: I apologize, that was not you. I am referring to the  debugging message.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above (provided by Muhibbullah Ansary) works fine, however, consider adding a container and putting a class or ID on it instead of using the BODY tag.

As others have mentioned, double check your URL.

It would also help us if you stated what your desired outcome is so that we don't have to guess, based on the code you've provided. it's possible that even though the code gets corrected, it still doesn't accomplish what you really wanted. Just a thought.

Answer (score -1):

```css
body{
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/949587/pexels-photo-949587.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: table;
}
```

Your image path is incorrect, correct this path.

Comment: using an absolute url from the internet is kind of a work-around, rather than a solution